# Join return one row of one to many relationship with two joined tables

Tags: sql-server

- Table `TRANS` contains transactional information (`transaction_id, date, foo, bar`)
- Table `ELEM` contains elements of the transaction (`transaction_id, detail_id`)
- Table `DET` contains details of the elements  (`detail_id, size, weight, category`)

Query:

```
select * from TRANS t 
join ELEM e on (t.transaction_id = e.transaction_id)
join DET d on (e.detail_id = d.detail_id)
```

However, `TRANS` may have one of more `ELEM/DET` rows associated with it. So if I have 100 rows in `TRANS` and run the query, I will return > 100 rows which is not desired.

I do however want to know how many transactions have `DET` rows with `d.category=1`, but if I join with that condition, I get < 100 rows (only the rows with that condition.

I want the cake and to eat it too. I want to retrieve all the `TRANS` rows within a date range, and also have I the result the number of rows where `d.category=1`. If `d.category != 1` then I don't care what is in there, as long as the `TRANS` row is still returned.

Comment: Do you want columns from `ELEM` and `DET` in the result, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid chaining LEFT JOINs.  You can end up with unexpected data.

NOTE: By this, I mean if you have:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b 
    ON a = b
LEFT JOIN c
    ON b = c
```

and b-c is strict 1:1, consider writing like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM b
    JOIN c
        ON b = c
) d
    ON a = d
```

So, you'd end up with *something* like:

```
SELECT *
FROM TRANS t
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT *  -- DON"T USE *, this will fail ^1
    FROM ELEM e
    JOIN DET d
         ON e.detail_id = d.detail_id
) a
    ON t.transaction_id = a.transaction_id
```

^1 - you can't select multiple columns with the same name in a subquery.  Be explicit, ALWAYS!!!

Comment: No prob.  Glad to help.  Remember join orders!  : )

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS TRANSCOUNT, SUM(CASE WHEN d.category=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CAT1COUNT
FROM TRANS t 
join ELEM e on (t.transaction_id = e.transaction_id)
join DET d on (e.detail_id = d.detail_id)
```

The case statement will only count rows (1 for each row in the full join results) when d.category is 1.

OK, I missed the table explanations at the top of your post.  You may want

```
select count(distinct detail_id)
```

or

```
select count(distinct transaction_id)
```

in there too; I'm not completely sure which one you're asking for

Comment: the distinct works in getting the counts to match up (which is the example I gave) but I need to return the actual row/data.

Comment: Which actual row/data do you need?  Your example only gave a count(1)...  You want the TRANS row?  Or each ELEM and DET information too?

Comment: the count was how I validated the number of returned rows, I have edited it to remove confusion.  I want TRANS + ELEM + DET for rows that have d.category=1.  If I already returned a TRANS row, I don't want any others, but I need at least 1 TRANS row for each.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear but I think you want to join first the `ELEM` and `DET` tables (with the `category=1` restriction) and then `LEFT JOIN` the `TRANS` table to the previous construction (the parentheses are not needed at all, they are added for clarity of precedence):

```
select t.*, d.* 
from 
        TRANS t 
    left join 
        (     ELEM e 
          join 
              DET d 
            on  d.detail_id = e.detail_id
            and d.category = 1
        ) 
      on  t.transaction_id = e.transaction_id 
where
    ( d.date range_condition ) ;
```